# Javascript inner function with colon

Tags: javascript, function

I know that you can write following

```js
var obj = {
    test: 'something'
}
```

But in this code, the inner function does not refer to a variable, but to a function.

Is there any other way to write / call the inner function?

```js
function outer(){
    
    var a = "Outerfunction";
    console.log(a)
            
    innerFct: function InnerFct()    {                                              
        var c = "Inner";
        console.log(c)
    } innerFct();
}
window.outer();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of different things going on here.

In this code:

```
var obj = {
    test: 'something'
}
```

you are using "literal object notation" to create -- well, an object with one property `test` and that property has a value of `something`

In your second case, you are creating a code block (yes, it is fun that both objects and code blocks use the same syntax `{...}` to define them.

Inside of a code block, the `innerFct:` becomes a label.  Labels are used with some control flow statements to jump around.  Forget about them, you really are better off not using them.

```
function outer(){
    var a = "Outerfunction";
    console.log(a)

    function innerFct()    {                                              
        var c = "Inner";
        console.log(c)
    }
    innerFct();
}
outer();
```

or even

```
function outer(){
    var a = "Outerfunction";
    console.log(a)

    var innerFct = function ()    {                                              
        var c = "Inner";
        console.log(c)
    }
    innerFct();
}
outer();
```

Comment: thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for. Yes I know, that the first one was a literal object, but I wonder why the function works with ":"

Comment: Your original code throws an error: `ReferenceError: innerFct is not defined` for me. What browser are you using where it works?

Comment: @ChristophHa -- More info on labels: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: Hi @JeremyJStarcher When I write below code:      `var myObject{  function talk(){  console.log('Hello world');  }  }`  myObject.talk() but it throw me an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: Correct, it is a syntax error.  Google 'Revealing Module Pattern' for lots of discussion on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing `functions` with `objects`.

When using an object, the colon is used to show key-value pairs.

```
var object = {
  innerFct: function(){
    console.log('rawr');
  },
  someVariable: 7
}

object.innerFct(); //logs rawr
object.someVariable = 4; //just changed from 7 to 4
```

Using a colon how you have it in your example is incorrect syntax. Also when you are creating a function within an object like that, you don't name the function again because you are already assigning it to a name on the object.

Then you can edit the function anytime by doing something like this:

```
object.innerFct = function(){
  //new code
}
```

Doing `object.innerFct()` will call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have sufficiently covered the object syntax and calling the function in scope. As I mentioned in the comment, you can just do this:

```
function outer(){
    (function () {
        var c = "inner";
        console.log(c)
    })();
}
window.outer();
```

And it logs `inner` just fine.

**Edit:** Private/hidden variables like `innerFct` in the original code sample can be captured in closures as well.

```
outer = function() {
    var innerFct = function () { console.log("inner"); }
    // innerFct is captured in the closure of the following functions
    // so it is defined within the scope of those functions, when they are called
    // even though it isn't defined before or after they complete
    window.wrapper = function() { innerFct(); }
    return function() { innerFct(); }
}
outer();

// each of these next three lines logs "inner"
window.wrapper();   // assigned to global variable
outer()();          // calling the returned function
var innerFctBackFromTheDead = outer(); // saving the returned function
innerFctBackFromTheDead();
```

There is also the object constructor/prototype syntax.

```
function Outer() {
    this.inner = function() {
        this.c = "inner";
        console.log(this.c);
    }
}

var out = new Outer();
out.c;       // undefined
out.inner(); // logs "inner"
out.c;       // "inner"
```

More information on the new keyword and prototypes: http://pivotallabs.com/javascript-constructors-prototypes-and-the-new-keyword/