# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in Object Literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm learning using Javascript Object Literal, I also tested this javascript in Chrome's Javascript console and it returned `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier`

**Working code**

```
"use strict";

var myObject = {
    foo: 'bar',

    talk : function(){
        console.log('Hello world')
    }
}

myObject.talk();
console.log(myObject.foo);
```

But If I change to `function talk(){}`

```
"use strict";

var myObject = {
    foo: 'bar',

    function talk(){
        console.log('Hello world')
    }
}

myObject.talk();
console.log(myObject.foo);
```

It throw an above error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier`. Thank in advance.

Comment: You're not assigning the `function talk()` to a an object.

Comment: like properties, you make methods for objects: `talk: function(){};` You call the method like this myObject.talk();

Comment: Object literals are of the form `{key: value, ...}`. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Hi @FelixKling I know it, but in this topic http://stackoverflow.com/a/15128163/3127538 he told that we better off not using them so I try another method.

Comment: You misunderstood the question/answer. The answer talks about not using [**labels**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), which has nothing to do with object literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct syntax to assign a function to a property:

```
var myObject = {
    foo: 'bar',
    talk: function thisNameIsOptional() {
        console.log('Hello world')
    }
};
```

Also you can do it this way:

```
var myObject = {
    foo: 'bar',
    talk: talk
};

function talk() {
    console.log('Hello world')
}
```

As you see the syntax is always the same:

```
{
    literal1: (object or function),
    literal2: (object or function)

    ... and so on ...

}
```

The second one on your question is wrong.

If this is not enough, you have [a complete guide for variables and literals on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals).

Comment: Hi @lante How can I assign `function name(){}` to a property?

Comment: I just edited my answer to give you an alternative way to bind a function to a property

Comment: Thank @lante so much, I know a little more via your example :D

Answer (score 1):

Object literals doesnt work that way like constructor functions.

Like lante said, you have to set an identifier and assign a value (or function) to it to make it work. It's basically like an array with key/value pairs.

The code for a constructor function (as another method):

```
function myObject() {
    this.foo = 'bar';
    this.talk = function() {
        alert('talk fired');
    }
}

var obj = new myObject();
obj.talk();
```

The difference between constructor functions and object literals are: Constructor functions can have private functions and properties, where literals have always public access (except you are using internal functions). `this.talk()` is a public function which can be called externally. If you type `function talk()` instead of `this.talk` then it's private and can't be called via `obj.talk();`

Comment: Thank you for explationation :)

Answer (score 0):

Example is here:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

When you create an object in javascript (one of ways), you are creating a dictionary of objects. And the method for doing this is assigning :

```
{
objectName: objectValue (value or function),
...
}
```

In your second example you had made 2 mistakes (that's why it doesn't compile):
- you can define named functions inside other functions (scopes), but object declaration is not one of it
- you need to assign this function to a name, that will be a pointer to it in this object

Thats why your first option is correct, while second is not.

Comment: I hope I wrote it easy to understand

Comment: w3schools should not be treated as a reference. The adequate reference is the ECMAScript standard.